# Folium map keeps greying out when I zoom in

Tags: python, maps, folium

I had included folium maps in my PyQt application. But when I try zooming in, the map just greys out. I had set the zoom to 14 initially, 15 or higher would cause it to freeze/grey out.

Here is my code:

```py
coordinate = (32.6, -97.4)
m = folium.Map(
    tiles='Stamen Terrain',
    zoom_start=14,
    location=coordinate,
    Popup="Start"  
)
```